# Google Calendar API integration with Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate `Google Calender API` in my Project. I found one good tutorial. Source : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565032/Google-Calendar-Integration-in-ASP-NET-Create-ed

It is also working fine. But now, As I have checked **It asks for Permission from Google to access Information, instead of this I want to grant direct permission.**
Next is, It opens `Google Calender` on `Google Calender` website like : https://www.google.com/calendar/render But I want to open it in my website only as a iFrame.
Please help me regarding this.